# What is the max enchantment level using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What is the highest level of enchantment that is possible to obtain?

Note that I am not talking about the maximum *effective* enchantment level, I am talking about the maximum number that can be displayed (or attempted to display) on the tooltip, regardless of whether said enchantment would function at that level.

If you are looking for the maximum *effective* enchantment level, please see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/262999/145151).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.13+ players, please see the other answer.

## 1.12−

Enchantment levels are saved as a Short, with a minimum of -32,768 and maximum of 32,767.

```
/give @p minecraft:stone 1 0 {ench:[{id:16s,lvl:32767s}]}
```

You can find further information on the NBT format [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/NBT_format).

Comment: **THIS ANSWER IS INACCURATE.** Please see my answer below for the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Maximum *displayable* enchantment level

This answer shows the maximum enchantment level that can be *displayed* on the item tooltip. See [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/387909/250180) for the maximum *effective* enchantment levels.

## 1.17+ Update

From the Minecraft Wiki:

> **lvl:** The level of the enchantment, where 1 is level 1. Values are clamped between 0 and 255 when reading.

This means that the maximum enchantment level is 255. Affix an `s` to the end of the number to mark it as a Short tag, to take up the least memory.

## 1.13+ Update

From the Minecraft Wiki:

> **lvl**: The level of the enchantment, where 1 is level 1. Saved as short when created by enchanting tables or loot tables, but read as an int and supports full int range.

In layman's terms, the Survival means like loot tables, anvils, and enchanting tables save the number as a Short, but when they are actually applied to items, they are read as an Integer.

Therefore, you don't need to stick to the Short data type just because that is what the enchantment tables use. You are allowed to use the Integer data type because that is how the enchantment levels are *read*.

The maximum integer is 2,147,483,647.

```
/give @s netherite_sword{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness",lvl:2147483647}]}
```

---

## Side notes...

- Some users are suggesting that higher enchantment levels are possible, like 2,177,548,418,058. These numbers are from [Phoenix SC's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YtTbYrH3XE), where the title is *"Duplicating OP Enchantments in Minecraft"*. This shows that the big number was only obtained by stacking enchantments, and is not the maximum level of a single enchantment. You can do what they did and stack your enchantments to obtain higher levels.
- Do note that attempting to exceed the maximum enchantment level using commands will *not* return an error, but note that the item you receive will have the enchantment level 0.
  This is because the invalid numbers [become strings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374852/250180) when inputted incorrectly, and because Minecraft is looking for an integer in the level, it does not register the number because it is a string!

Comment: Do you know what version the change happened in?

Comment: I'm wrong on most of these things, but maybe say "this changed in 1.13" or something in the question so it doesn't sound like the other answer is just wrong? You don't have to and may not want to do this, though, as I know many other people here don't like that (*I just don't want to be the dude running around giving people bad/incorrect information*).

Comment: yes! That is great for the reader - do you know why some of the other people don't like that? Whenever I do that the edits get rejected, hence me giving the warning in my previous comment

Answer (score -1):

Well it is basically (not?) infinite! You can make a weapon so powerful that it could kill it instantly (if you have sharpness)! Here is the command for an example /give @a minecraft:diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:16s,lvl:1000}]}

Comment: No, incorrect. There *is* a limit.

Comment: Nothing is infinite. Memory can only be stored as long as there is a place for it to go, and while you may not think about it, the size can exceed what it can be held, like your computer can't have a sum of file sizes larger than the hard drive allows. Eventually you would have to either make the results less precise to save space, or just have a limit entirely. Either way, the ench lvl is a short (which maybe is read as an int according to ExpertCoder14's answer).

Answer (score -1):

The maximum enchantment level is actually 2177548418058.
Try the following command:

```
/give @p diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:"sharpness",lvl:2147483647}]}
```

Comment: Your actual command only has `0x7FFFFFFF` in it though. The number you claim before is quite a bit higher...

Comment: Looks like you watched [Phoenix SC's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YtTbYrH3XE) on this... but he put on enchantments of level `0x7FFFFFFF` (2147483647). Seems that really is the maximum. He just 'cheated' around the limit by adding that same enchant multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

**2177548418058**

Try:

```
/give @s netherite_sword{Enchantments:[{id:"sharpness",lvl:2177548418058}]}
```

You can also add multiple enchantments:

```
/give @s netherite_sword{Enchantments:[{id:"sharpness",lvl:2177548418058},{id:knockback,lvl:2177548418058}]}
```

All you need to do is put a comma and put another enchantment, as shown above.

Comment: Your command is incorrect: the tooltip now displays `Sharpness.enchantment.level.0` instead of `Sharpness.enchantment.level.2177548418058`. Please check your commands and setup.