# Do Sharpness and Smite enchantments stack damage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

With a command block I am able to provide sharpness and smite to the same weapon. Do the effects of this stack?

Comment: Yes I know that the two damage types can not be put on a weapon naturally.

Comment: @JustAGuest No, you cannot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the damage stacks.

To test this I gave myself 4 weapons:
**Sword 1:** No enchantments
**Sword 2:** Sharpness V
**Sword 3:** Smite V
**Sword 4:** Sharpness V and Smite V

I then added an objective to track the damage I have dealt:

```
/scoreboard objectives add damageDealt stat.damageDealt
```

And summoned a skeleton with a lot of health:

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~ ~ {Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:3000}],Health:3000}
```

Against the skeleton, for each weapon, the damageDealt statistics would consistently show:

**Sword 1:** `70` damage
[image]

**Sword 2:** `100` damage
[image]

**Sword 3:** `195` damage
[image]

**Sword 4:** `225` damage
[image]

So the Sharpness V adds `30` damage (1.5 hearts), the Smite V adds `125` damage (6.25 hearts) and both together add `155` damage (7.75), which is 30 + 125.

Therefore, it appears as though extra damages simply add with each other.

Comment: This is the correct answer. For technical details, I have a post [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/262999/what-is-the-highest-effective-enchantment-level/263013#263013) describing how the source combines all the Sharpness-like enchantments together into the same modifier.

Comment: Just wondering if this is still true, wiki says they're mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Cestarian The wiki likely means you can't normally put them both on the same weapon.

Comment: Ah that's right.